# Make the photos taken by Android Camera app and Google Camera app smaller when created?

Tags: camera, google-camera

The photos taken by either Android Camera app or Google Camera app are too large when created. Is it possible to change some settings in the two apps to make the photos  smaller when created? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For the Google Camera app:

1. Drag from the left screen edge to show the menu
2. Select the settings "gear" icon in the lower right
3. Select "resolution & quality"
4. Select which camera you want to change the resolution and select a smaller size

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest what resolution is good yet not too large for what case?